# TransformerHandler throws OutOfMemoryError with large xml files

Tags: java, xml, sax

I'm using SAXTransformerFactory to new a TransformerHandler to generate xml.
the problem is that for large amount of content i get a OutOfMemoryError.

Find out that there are a lot classes in memory including

```
    oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLElement
    char[]
    oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLText
    oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLAttr
```

Even after endDocument, the classes are still existed.

Simple Example

```
 public class Test
    {
         /**
          * test handler memory usage
          * @param loops no of loops - when large enogh - OutOfMemoryError !!!
      * @param xsltFilePath xslt file
      * @param targetXmlFile output xml file
      * @throws Exception
      */
     public static void testHandlerMemUsage(int loops, String xsltFilePath, String targetXmlFile)throws Exception
     {
          //verify SAX support
          TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
          if(!factory.getFeature(SAXTransformerFactory.FEATURE))
               throw new UnsupportedOperationException("SAX tranformations not supported");
          TransformerHandler handler=
               ((SAXTransformerFactory)factory).newTransformerHandler(new StreamSource(xsltFilePath));
          handler.setResult(new StreamResult(targetXmlFile));

          handler.startDocument();
          handler.startElement(null,"root","root",new AttributesImpl());
          //loop
          for(int i=0;i<loops;i++)
          {
               handler.startElement(null,"el-"+i,"el-"+i,new AttributesImpl());
               handler.characters("value".toCharArray(),0,"value".length());
               handler.endElement(null,"el-"+i,"el-"+i);
          }
          handler.endElement(null,"root","root");
          //System.out.println("end document");
          //only after endDocument() starts to print..
          handler.endDocument();
          //System.out.println("ended document");
     }

     public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
     {
          System.out.println("--starting..");
          testHandlerMemUsage(500000,"/copy.xslt","/testHandlerMemUsage.xml");
          System.out.println("--we are still here -- increase loops..");
     }
}
```

Comment: what is the size of your heap?

Comment: Generally you can expect that if the source document is of size M, the amount of memory you need to allocate will be around 5*M - though it obviously depends a bit which XSLT processor you are using and exactly what the transformation is doing.

Comment: The file generated is 110M, and the heap is used abut 663M, I'm not sure what the transformation really do, and even after the endDocument, the classes still exists, when I run gc with JProfiler manually, the classes not decrease.

Comment: Read once on some website that memory size used is related to the depth of column tag, but it seems not.    my xml file structure like:<columns><column><a></a><b></b><c></c></column><column><a></a><b></b><c></c></column></columns>  The max depth is 4, and there will be lots of column tag , about 372833 column tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-Xmx` command line parameter when invoking `java` to increase the heap size of your process, e.g.:

```
java -Xmx1g ...
```